# Short word to describe someone wearing smartglasses

Tags: single-word-requests, slang, business-language

My company is developing smart eyewear and **I'm looking for a short word to describe the users of our smartglasses for English documents**.

The ideal wording would be understandable by British, US, and international audiences. It's primarily intended for internal usage, product specification, and exchanges with partners. It doesn't need to be formal; it can be some mild slang instead as long as it's generally friendly. We want to be able to use it openly in user documentation.

It can't simply be 'users', because we also have other kinds of 'users' of our products who won't necessarily be using the smartglasses.

**So far I like the sound of 'speckies' or 'speccies'** found in online dictionaries. Do they sound appropriate to you or would you have anything else to suggest?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79589/discussion-on-question-by-yoann-h-short-word-to-describe-someone-wearing-smartgl).

Comment: When a word request attracts a long list of ideas, that is a clear signal that either the criteria are unclear or the question is more of a poll or request for a list of things, neither of which are a good fit for the Stack Exchange model.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

> **[eyeglass wearer](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/eyeglass+wearer)**
>   a person who wears spectacles in order to see better

If there's a brand you could substitute "eyeglass" with the name of the product, e.g. *Persol wearer*

Comment: eyeglasses "user" is more the sense wanted here.  Like, in a marketing department you'd say "There are 31.2 eyeglass users in the nation...".  Not "wearers".

Comment: 'Wearer' gained traction internally (along with 'user'), so I'm marking this first answer suggesting keeping it as the accepted one.
Thank you all for your help and very rich discussions!

Comment: @yoann-h Oh, thanks very much. Goof of you to let us know. In reply to Fattie's comment: The OP said *It can't simply be 'users', because we also have other kinds of 'users' of our products who won't necessarily be using the smartglasses.*

Answer (score 69):

## bespectacled

> wearing eyeglasses ~ [*dictionary.com*](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/bespectacled)

In a sentence: *Bill Gates, Woody Allen, John Lennon, Gandhi and Steve Jobs are known as famous, bespectacled men.*

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79590/discussion-on-answer-by-michael-b-short-word-to-describe-someone-wearing-smartgl).

Answer (score 36):

You've already used a good word in your question. "Wearers of glasses", shortened during use to simply **"wearers"**.

Some people may *use* your glasses, but the majority of them have to do so by *wearing* them

Answer (score 2):

I suggest creating the term `enlensed`:

> The enlensed multiply with each passing day; it is unclear how long we can hold out.

Answer (score 1):

It's Personal Eyesight Correction. Or Person with Eyesight Correction. And 'pec' or 'pecs' trips off the tongue nicely. Since it's a new word, it could be a noun. I suppose you could even go as far as saying Special Personal Eyesight Correction...

Answer (score 1):

Consider "visually impaired".

According to dictionary.com:

> adjective
>
> having any defect of vision, whether disabling or not (as collective
>   noun; preceded by the)the visually impaired See partially sighted

It doesn't necessarily imply that the person currently has eyeglasses on, but within the context of your question, where you state that "it's primarily intended for internal usage, product specification and exchanges with partners," it distinguishes your users who need to wear glasses on occassion from your users who don't.

Comment: I upvoted this when I thought that the question was about normal wearers of eyegear ('gearheads'?) and I think 'VIP' (visually impaired person/people) would be excellent business jargon for customers... but it doesn't really work at all for describing the wearers of smartglasses, many of whom are not going to be visually impaired at all.

Comment: I thought smartglasses were just a specific style, I didn't realize what they were. The OP didn't expand on that at all.

Comment: You're right. We should probably edit the question to elaborate on that...

Answer (score 0):

How about "corrective lens users" or "corrective lens wearers"?

I rarely wear my glasses, as I have my contacts in most of the time.

The new multifocal contacts are like having reading glasses built in, so no reading glasses are needed if the contacts to correct for near sightedness are normally worn.

I know, 3 words vs 1, but seems more technically correct to me.

Comment: Might be even politically correct, but the OP asked for something short. This isn't.

Comment: I love the idea (which isn't politically correct) of calling them the 'lensmen' but this doesn't fit the actual question, which is about wearers of smartglasses and not regular glasses.

Answer (score -2):

"owner" as in "The owner of these glasses will be able to see..."
[Owner Definition](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/owner?s=t)

After reading the other comments, just go with "user" or "wearer".  It will sound far better than trying to use some cute, novel word like "bespectacled".  Most English speakers won't have any trouble understanding you if you say "the wearer should be careful" or anything else along those lines.  Don't try to over complicate it.  Using terms like that will actually make it harder to understand what you're trying to say by burying the information under a lot of fluffy words.

Old: "four-eyed" if you want to add a bit of snarkyness.

Comment: add a dictionary link to 4-eyed and your answer will garner more support

Comment: @Technophile did the OP ask for slang and use the slang tag? yes.

Comment: @CMB, OP said " it can be some mild slang instead as long as it's friendly". Four-eyed is not friendly.

Comment: That's my bad.  I didn't read through the post very carefully and didn't realize what you were asking about it for.  Thought it was just a writing thing.  Derp.

Comment: +1 Please highlight **"wearer"**. OP already explained that "user" is too broad (please delete that), and "four-eyed" is silly.

Comment: @smci  I think having three answers suggesting "wearers" is silly and counterproductive. Two is more than enough.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: both "user" and "four-eyed" are excluded by the question. That only leaves "wearer".

Comment: I'm not adding "wearer" or "user" as new options, but supporting them as good words already supplied by other people.  They may seem generic, but the truth is that simplicity is usually better.  Trying to throw in a bunch of overly florid words to describe a person wearing glasses is going to make it harder for the user to get through your instructions while making your English sound poor.  I know you'd prefer not to use "user," but "The user can then..." or "The wearer can then..." will sound a lot better to most English speakers than "The bespectacled person can then..."

Comment: Then downvote 'bespectacled'. You don't really need to belabor the point that you wish he'd say that 'user' was an acceptable answer when it isn't.

Answer (score -4):

**specky** or **speckies** (informal) one who wears spectacles; often used attributively  [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/specky)

As you said:

> It's primarily intended for internal usage, product specification and
>   exchanges with partners.

My sense of a word you first suggested ... is perfect!  PS: Here is one business that has no compunction in openly using [specky](http://specky.store).

[image: speckies.com]

Another business: Amazon.com: **Specky** Full-Rimless Business Frame Clear Lens ...

and:  Pritam is the “**Specky** Geek” with really high-power spectacles sitting on his nose.

[image: specky geek]

Comment: Downvoted as providing a list of insults associated with those who wear eyeglasses.  Is it your intention to actually aid the OP in marketing their product?

Comment: new answer by me

Comment: `Possible criterion: acceptable if we can use it openly in user documentation.` So you would use this term in a document that is viewable to the general public, as in "Speckies suggested that [brand] customer service needed improvement" Hmm...

Answer (score -5):

You could use [myope](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/myope). Obviously not everyone wearing glasses has myopia, but if you're just after a shorthand, this could suffice:

> A short-sighted person. -- [*Oxford Dictionaries*](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/myope)

Comment: more to the point, not everyone short-sighted wears glasses...

Comment: @Orangesandlemons that's also fine. My understanding is the use case only asks for a word which makes it clear its referring to the bespectacled. "bespectacled" is a perfect word but it's a bit of a mouthful; myope is substantially more fluent and I think evokes the right first impression.

Comment: And not everyone wearing glasses is short-sighted...

Comment: @Tim as stated "Obviously not everyone wearing glasses has myopia"

Comment: Note that the OP says they are in the 'smart eyewear' business, e.g. google glass, not corrective eyewear.

Comment: To be fair, I interpreted "smart eyewear" as being, like, Warby Parkers. There's more than one dictionary definition for "smart," you know! (And I'm sure I qualify for at least one of the others... /s)

Answer (score -5):

Nerd

> informal
>
> 1. foolish or contemptible person who lacks social skills or is boringly studious.
>
> ‘I was a serious nerd until I discovered girls and cars’

https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/nerd

Comment: This addresses the title, but not the rest of the question. "Nerd" is clearly not an option for use in documentation to disambiguate glasses wearers. But colloquially accurate.

Comment: @DanielB It's not colloquially adequate at all. 'Nerd' has nothing *per se* to do with glasses.

Comment: "Boring" is in the eye of the beholder.  One person's obsession is another's "why would anyone want to do that?". For examples, see the list of hobby shows in your area.